# Eigenvalues in a Matrix with 3 unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm in a Linear Algebra class, where we are currently covering eigenvalues and eigenvectors. My question is how should I solve this exercise with three variables?

> Consider the matrix
>   \begin{equation*}
>     A := \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 0 & a \\
>     b & c & 10 \\
>     0 & 0 & a
>     \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}
>   Question: **What value or values ​​should the parameters take for matrix A to have three real eigenvalues
>   equal?**

I'm will solve this using: $\det(A- \lambda I)$: 
\begin{equation*}
    \det\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & a \\
    b & c & 10 \\
    0 & 0 & a
    \end{bmatrix}
    -\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\ 0&\lambda&0\\ 0&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda&0&a\\ b&c-\lambda&10\\ 0&0&a-\lambda\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
After we got the determinant we have:
\begin{align*}(-\lambda)(c-\lambda)(a-\lambda)=0\end{align*}

How should I proceed to answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of that polynomial are $0$, $a$, and $c$. So, you have only one eigenvalue if and only if $a=c=0$.

Comment: So the answer for: "What value or values ​​should the parameters take for matrix A to have three real eigenvalues equal?"
   Would be:
a=0 and c=0?

Comment: Yeah, as you have shown, $0$ is an eigen value clearly no matter what $a,c$ are. So the other two must also be $0$, i.e. $a=c=0$

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the question. I thought that you were after $3$ *distinct* eigenvalues. I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds on the one given by Jose Carlos Santos. He is correct in saying that the roots of the polynomial are 0, a, and c. In other words, λ = 0, λ = a, and λ = c are the eigenvalues of that system. If you want all 3 eigenvalues to be equal, then a = c = 0.
Furthermore, b can then take any value.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, we know that both $a$ and $c$ are eigenvalues: $A(0,1,0)^T=(0,c,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1)A=(0,0,a)$. Since all of the eigenvalues must be equal, $a=c$. The trace of $A$ is equal to $a+c=2a$, so the third eigenvalue must be $0$, therefore $a=c=0$. The value of $b$ is unconstrained.